# local development for euclid the game

Tags: javascript, html, local

I am trying to do some local development for http://euclidthegame.com/

I forked the project from github https://github.com/kasperpeulen/euclidthegame, and cloned it onto my local computer - running windows 7.

When I tried to load the index.html page in chrome it opened a page [with the location file:///C:/Users/hp250G3/Documents/euclid_the_game/index.html] and after what seemed to be an eternity (more than a minute, less than 3) tried to  redirect to  the file called tutorial (because it finds that I am a new user), but the path it was trying to redirect to was file:///C:/Tutorial/, instead of file:///C:/Users/hp250G3/Documents/euclid_the_game/tutorial.html

Changing  line 16 in the index.html file to url=tutorial, still resulted in -  cannot load page as file does not exist, and changing to  url=tutorial.html opened a page which contained just the text of the tutorial without the images or the geogebra framework.

Clearly changing the name, or rather the location, of the files isn't the solution.

How can I get the game to display correctly in my browser?

Comment: You'll have to set up a local webserver.

Comment: I installed xampp. Should I now clone the project into c:\xampp\htdocs\, or is there another way to serve the pages from the current local file location?